# User controll into class library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library

How to include user control to class library? Or how to show custom view from dll? Windows Phone 8.1 runtime. [image]

Answer (score 1):

On the page you are wanting to add the UserControl(I'm assuming AdView), at the top you will see some XML Namespace declarations.  They look like this:

```
xmlns:x="using:System"
```

You need to add one that looks like this:

```
xmlns:google="using:GoogleAds"
```

Or whatever the proper namespace is for the control you are trying to add to your page.

Once you've done that, you can add the control like this:

```
<google:AdView x:Name="adView" otherProperty="Value" />
```

Comment: I mean how can I do like google? If I include user control to class library and than use it I have some errors with xaml.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your XAML and the errors you have?

Comment: See. Now my Class Library has 2 xaml pages. To use need add reference to dll and the dll must keep in folder with struct like:
[folder](http://prntscr.com/5crw83)

But google use only single dll.